# My dog is too quiet

Tags: dogs, behavior

Actually it is my boyfriend's dog.  The first time I saw her, she was very exited and jumped into my body.  A year later when she came to my place, she was at first very exited too, I could see by her tail curving up.  But moments after she become very quiet, never barked, and did not respond when we called her.

Note that my boyfriend comes home less often since he got his new job, because he stays over at my place.  His dog stay at home with his brother and he rarely play with her.  Is that the reason my dog seems to be depressed?

One day I tried to pinch her ear, and she did not even responded when I hurt her.  Normally a dog will cry out when you accidentally hurt it.  What is happening to her?

Also, she becomes over exited and can't control her behavior when I walk her, often chasing strangers and other dogs.

Comment: Regarding the failure to react to a pain stimulus: get to veterinarian ASAP, please.  It could be mere depression, but this could be a sign of serious neurological issue as well.  The vet may have insights on the other problems as well, but that one needs to be your first concern.